# Command line generated address can't recover with seed phrase, what am I missing?

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, openssl, ruby

I have generated a bitcoin address using the following commands along with a ruby script for compression.

First I generate a key using `echo "24 word seed phrase BIP 39" | openssl sha256`

Then run the below Ruby script to compress the key

```
# example private key
private_key = "private key that has been generated with previous command"

# --------------------------
# Secp256k1 Curve Parameters
# --------------------------
# y^2 = x^3 + ax + b
$a = 0
$b = 7 # using global variables for convenience

# prime modulus
$p = 2 ** 256 - 2 ** 32 - 2 ** 9 - 2 ** 8 - 2 ** 7 - 2 ** 6 - 2 ** 4 - 1

# number of points on the curve
$n = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337

# generator point (the starting point on the curve used for all calculations)
$g = {
  x: 55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240,
  y: 32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424,
}

# --------------------------
# Elliptic Curve Mathematics
# --------------------------
# Modular Inverse - Ruby doesn't have a built-in function for finding modular inverses, so here's one using the extended Euclidean algorithm.
def modinv(a, m = $p)
  a = a % m if a < 0 # make sure a is positive
  prevy, y = 0, 1
  while a > 1
    q = m / a
    y, prevy = prevy - q * y, y
    a, m = m % a, a
  end
  return y
end

# Double - Add a point on the curve to itself.
def double(point)
  # slope = (3x^2 + a) / 2y
  slope = ((3 * point[:x] ** 2) * modinv((2 * point[:y]))) % $p # using modular inverse to perform "division"

  # new x = slope^2 - 2x
  x = (slope ** 2 - (2 * point[:x])) % $p

  # new y = slope * (x - new x) * y
  y = (slope * (point[:x] - x) - point[:y]) % $p

  # return x, y coordinates of point
  return { x: x, y: y }
end

# Add - Add two points together.
def add(point1, point2)
  # double if both points are the same
  return double(point1) if point1 == point2

  # slope = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)
  slope = ((point1[:y] - point2[:y]) * modinv(point1[:x] - point2[:x])) % $p

  # new x = slope^2 - x1 - x2
  x = (slope ** 2 - point1[:x] - point2[:x]) % $p

  # new y = slope * (x1 - new x) - y1
  y = ((slope * (point1[:x] - x)) - point1[:y]) % $p

  # return x, y coordinates of point
  return { x: x, y: y }
end

# Multiply - Use the double and add operations to quickly multiply a point by an integer (e.g. a private key).
def multiply(k, point = $g) # multiply the generator point by default
  # create a copy the initial starting point (for use in addition later on)
  current = point

  # convert integer to binary representation (for use in the double and add algorithm)
  binary = k.to_s(2)

  # double and add algorithm for fast multiplication
  binary.split("").drop(1).each do |char| # ignore first binary character
    # 0 = double
    current = double(current)

    # 1 = double and add
    if char == "1"
      current = add(current, point)
    end
  end

  # return the final point
  return current
end

# -------------------------
# Private Key To Public Key
# -------------------------
# convert private key to an integer
k = private_key.to_i(16)

# multiply generator point by this private key
point = multiply(k, $g) # this point is the public key

# convert x and y values of this point to hexadecimal
x = point[:x].to_s(16).rjust(64, "0")
y = point[:y].to_s(16).rjust(64, "0")

# uncompressed public key format (not used much these days, just showing how it looks)
public_key_uncompressed = "04" + x + y

# compressed public key format (every x value has a y that could be one of two possible points)
if (point[:y] % 2 == 0)
  prefix = "02" # if y is even
else
  prefix = "03" # if y is odd
end

public_key_compressed = prefix + x # only uses the full x coordinate

# -------
# Results
# -------
puts private_key           #=> ef235aacf90d9f4aadd8c92e4b2562e1d9eb97f0df9ba3b508258739cb013db2
puts public_key_compressed
```

Then hashing the key again with
`echo compressed key from ruby script | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256`

Then `echo hashed key | xxd -r -p | openssl ripemd160`

And finally adding `00` to the key
`echo 00key | xxd -p -r | base58 -c && echo`

The address I get is able to receiving funds, but I can't recover using the 24 word seed phrase using BlueWallet import function. What am I doing wrong?

https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/public-key Link to Ruby Script

https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-generate-a-bitcoin-address-step-by-step-9d7fcbf1ad0b Link to Openssl Commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your private key, transform it into a WIF and then you should be able to import it to BlueWallet.

How to transform a private key into a WIF:
https://gist.github.com/t4sk/ac6f2d607c96156ca15f577290716fcc

Comment: Both answers were correct, I just used the bash script out of the git. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have conflated multiple things here and resulted in a potentially unspendable address, or at least very difficult to spend with standard wallet software.

Wallets that use 24 word seed phrases typically use [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) to produce 512 bits of entropy which is then used with [BIP 32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) to derive the private keys used in the wallet. Your process does not do any of that. You did not use BIP 39 to produce the entropy; you did not use that entropy with BIP 32 to derive private keys; and you did not use BIP 32 derived private keys to produce your address.

When you import your 24 words into a BIP 39 compatible wallet, they're not going to use your method of deriving the address. They're going to use BIP 39 and BIP 32 to create multiple addresses, none of which are the one you generated.

Since you do technically still have the private key, you can convert it into a [Wallet Import Format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) private key and import that into a wallet to be able to spend your funds.